# How to put a variable inside a browser context when using page.$eval() in Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to run a code like this:

```
    const login = "login";
    await page.$eval('#LoginForm_username', el => el.value = login);
```

It enters a `login` value inside a form field.

However, I keep getting a weird error:

> Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: login is not defined
>       at **puppeteer_evaluation_script**:1:19
>       at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (/home/denis/WEB/nlu/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/ExecutionContext.js:122:13)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)   -- ASYNC --
>       at ExecutionContext. (/home/denis/WEB/nlu/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:15)
>       at ElementHandle.$eval (/home/denis/WEB/nlu/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/JSHandle.js:436:50)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)   -- ASYNC --
>       at ElementHandle. (/home/denis/WEB/nlu/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:15)
>       at DOMWorld.$eval (/home/denis/WEB/nlu/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/DOMWorld.js:156:21)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)   -- ASYNC --
>       at Frame. (/home/denis/WEB/nlu/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:15)
>       at Page.$eval (/home/denis/WEB/nlu/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:347:29)
>       at Page. (/home/denis/WEB/nlu/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:112:23)
>       at crawlForSchedule (/home/denis/WEB/nlu/crawler.js:99:16)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

As far as I understand, it means that the `login` variable is out of browser context or something like this.

I've found that it's possible to pass a variable using the `page.evaluate()` function like this:

```
const links = await page.evaluate((evalVar) => {
  console.log(evalVar); // should be defined now
}, evalVar);
```

but how to do something like this with the `page.$eval()` function? Or how can I achieve the needed behavior (form field input) using the `page.evaluate()` function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a function / variable in Puppeteer page.$eval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63466772/how-to-pass-a-function-variable-in-puppeteer-page-eval)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const login = "login";
await page.evaluate(login => {
    document.querySelector('#LoginForm_username').value = login;
}, login);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the [puppeteer's documentation](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1), you can see where we can insert parameters.
We can see that the parameters are a [spreaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) array (...args) that is received in last.

```js
page.$eval(selector, pageFunction[, ...args])
```

So we pass the `selector` then the function to be evaluated `pageFunction` and finally the arguments to the `pageFunction` the `...args`.

```js
const login = "login" // Your variable
await page.$eval('#LoginForm_username', (el, loginValue) => { 
   el.value = loginValue
}, login);
```

- `el` is your element equivalent to `document.querySelector('#LoginForm_username')`
- `loginValue` is your **parameter** that will receive the variable `login` (or anything you want)
- And lastly you **pass the** `login variable` to the parameter `loginValue`

You can pass anything you want because `loginValue` is a parameter.
Example:

```js
await page.$eval('#LoginForm_username', (el, loginValue) => { 
 el.value = loginValue 
}, 'Denis');
```

Similar question answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66653134/14844591)